# Using one text file as a modified 'stencil' for other text files with forms

Tags: merge, templates, forms, plaintext, text-processors

(rephrasing the question for better clarity.)

Suppose I have 1000 text files. Each file is a textual form, with fixed field descriptions and headers, but the data is different. For example, file 1:

> ```
> The Foo Factory             Date:  2015-10-02
>
> Order Details
> -------------------------
> Order ID:          [   1    ]  Amount: [   1 ]
> Order Price:       [  12.34 ]
>
> Have a nice day.
> ```

and file 2:

> ```
> The Foo Factory             Date:  2016-01-11
>
> Order Details
> -------------------------
> Order ID:          [   7    ]  Amount: [  17 ]
> Order Price:       [ 543.21 ]
>
> Have a nice day.
> ```

etc. Now, suppose I went ahead and translated the field descriptions into French; and I deleted the values. So now I have:

> ```
> L'usine Foo                 Date:            
>
> Détails de commande
> -------------------------
> Nm.du Commande:   [        ]  Montant: [     ]
> Prix du Commande: [        ]
>
> Bonne journée.
> ```

I don't really speak French so ignore any mistakes here. Anyway, the positions of all fields are exactly the same, but the non-field-value text is different. I want to apply this replacement to all of the files. How do I achieve that?

Comment: What's your end goal?

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples: Changing the field descriptions for a textual "form output"; and I will eventually have many of these. Also, your nick is rather confusing. I don't mean to be rude, but - perhaps you should consider changing it.

Comment: Can you provide a before and after screenshot or use a code block to provide an example?

Comment: you "replaced the "template" text and dropped the "file-specific" data" that sounds like the file would now be empty.

Comment: Are you aware of regex?

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples: Yes I am, but a regex doesn't apply to pairs of files/streams. Also, see my edit regarding your previous comment.

Comment: I doubt anyone will understand your question. Just provide background of your situation and an example of the operation you want to perform.

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples: How about now?

Comment: It's easy to understand now. My goto tool for this kind of thing is Python.

Comment: Do you want a script for this? I already started writing it.

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples: I was actually assuming there was some tool that does this. Obviously something like a perl script reading from two files could do this. Also, a command which interleaves characters from two files would almost allow for this to be done with a single simple regex (but for the fact that the new field descriptions sometimes contain spaces).

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples: Yes there is. Plus, it's nicer like that anyway :-)

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: I meant _Winmerge_ does that.

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples: Come on, "what's the OS"? I'm a bit offended... do I sound like Windows guy to you? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You've already generated the formatting map so the only remaining work is regex replace. Generating the map is more difficult, especially for larger, more complicated text. I use *Sublime Text* for that. But the use case and further information isn't clear here, you should take it to softwarerecs.SE if it's important. I'm including a Python version anyway:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

SOURCE_DIRECTORY = ''
DEST_DIRECTORY = ''

replacements = ["L'usine Foo                 ",
"Détails de commande",
"Nm.du Commande:   ",
"Montant: ",
"Prix du Commande: ",
"Bonne journée."]

samples = ["The Foo Factory             ",
"Order Details",
"Order ID:          ",
"Amount: ",
"Order Price:       ",
"Have a nice day."]

for filename in os.listdir(SOURCE_DIRECTORY):
    with open(os.path.join(SOURCE_DIRECTORY, filename), 'r') as nctn:
        text = nctn.read()
    for i, val in enumerate(samples):
        text = text.replace(val, replacements[i])
    with open(os.path.join(DEST_DIRECTORY, filename), 'w') as nctn:
        nctn.write(text)
```

Comment: What I mean is that, if you have a very large file, the very act of determining what operations need to be done, would be laborious. Think, manually selecting a thousand lines of keywords to create your mapping with.

Comment: Oh, no no no, I don't want want to write a custom script that contains the pattern. I need something which takes any (new pattern file,working file) pair and does the job.